# Unable to use NSTask to write using Sandbox

Tags: macos, nstask, appstore-sandbox, code-signing-entitlements

I am having a hard time debugging an issue with NSTask.

I start NSTask using the following:

```
NSTask *convTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[convTask setLaunchPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath]];
[convTask setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"convTask", source, target, nil]];
[convTask launch];
[convTask waitUntilExit];
[convTask terminate];
```

So it is basically launching a task that is another instance of my running app. This task is supposed to convert **source** (a file) to **target** (another file). And that is not working only when activate Sandbox. But even in Sandbox mode, when I use my terminal to execute the app using the same parameter passed to **NSTask** then the **target** gets created.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the Console show any messages for sandboxd?

Comment: Nope no message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Entitlement Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW15):

> If your app employs a child process created with either the posix_spawn function or the NSTask class, you can configure the child process to inherit the sandbox of its parent.

and:

> To enable sandbox inheritance, a child target must use exactly two App Sandbox entitlement keys: com.apple.security.app-sandbox and com.apple.security.inherit. If you specify any other App Sandbox entitlement, the system aborts the child process.

I suspect that forking yourself won't be a successful strategy, since that would mean the parent has to have only those two entitlements, which wouldn't be very useful in the child process.

Comment: I have tried adding these two entitlements to my app no improvement.

Comment: As it says, if you have any other entitlements, the child process will simply abort, and if you have no other entitlements, you won't have permissions to write a file.  According to the documentation, I don't see how your current architecture can work.